# Field name doesn't have default value error while using factories in phpunit + laravel

Tags: laravel, phpunit

When I use Factories in a test class in phpunit, field value doesn't insert into database.
It returns error

```
General error: 1364 Field 'name' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert 
    into province() values ())
```

My factory is:
use Faker\Generator as Faker;

```
$factory->define(\App\Provinces::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'name' => $faker->name
    ];
});
```

Comment: Where and how are you calling the factory?

Comment: Share more code related this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved the problem.

This problem occurred because in the __construct method of `Provinces` model I missed this line:

```
parent::__construct($attributes);
```

So, my constructor should be like this:

```
public function __construct(array $attributes = [])
{
    parent::__construct($attributes);
}
```